Error: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error when making API requests from Flutter app
Error: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error when making API requests from Flutter app
Error: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=http://localhost:3000/proxy
i have used local proxy etc every thing please help
i tried proxy and everything still the same error

are you trying to make api calls to local server?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can you try this header while using it?
headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': '*/*'
    }


thanks for replying, but its still working i added "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
